# How to disable bloatware for secondary users?

Tags: root-access, samsung-galaxy-tab, magisk, bloatware

I have a rooted Samsung A7 Lite tablet. I rooted it and installed Ice Box from Google Play store. It is given root access in Magisk and I use it to disable some Samsung bloatware.

However I realize that these apps are installed on the secondary user that I created. In the secondary user, Magisk app does not detect root status and Ice Box cannot obtain root access either. Non root mode of Ice Box doesn't work either because that requires that there is no additional users (according to its doc) so that defeats the purpose.

I wonder if there's a way to disable the bloatware in the secondary user from the owner user, or delete them completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable root on the secondary user:

- In Magisk settings → multi user mode, select *user-independent*.
- Install Magisk Manager *only* on secondary user (in case, it's not present) , optionally reboot and check if secondary user has root.

You can then use Ice Box to debloat.

Comment: On my device, Magisk was already installed in the secondary user. Before setting it to user-independent, it did not work in the secondary user (that it did not detect the root). After changing this setting as suggested in this answer, once switched to the secondary user, Magisk can detect root and can grant root access to apps that request for it.

Comment: Thanks. Edited the answer to add your input